# Plural weekday when listing dates

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Are any of the following correct?

> 1) Mondays, January 4, 11, 18, & 25   (plural weekday)
>
> 2) Monday, January 4, 11, 18 & 25    (singular weekday)
>
> 3) Mondays, January 4, 11, 18 & 25    (plural weekday, no comma before the ampersand)
>
> 4) Monday, January 4, 11, 18, & 25     (singular weekday, with a comma before the
>   ampersand)

Also, do you put a comma before the ampersand?

Thank you for any help in this.

Comment: The ampersand remarks do not match the examples.

Comment: Sorry about the mix up on the ampersand. The examples are correct. I just mixed up what I was trying to say in the parenthesis.

Comment: I meant (no comma) and (with comma) sorry.

Comment: 2) and 4) are still the same. Please pay attention to detail, when you are asking about detail.

Comment: Mondays in January: 4, 11, 18 & 25//that's simpler.

Comment: In what context? Normally you would start with "Each Monday", "On Mondays" or such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of a comma before ampersand or "and" comes down to whether you follow a British based form of English or an American one.

As to whether the day should be plural or singular, both are acceptable given certain contexts that you'd have to provide. E.g.

...on the following Mondays: ...

... on Monday the 4th, 11th, 18th and 25th of January.

Please also note that the ordering of the day and month varies from country to country.

Comment: Is the comma before the ampersand or "and" the British based version or American based version?

Comment: It is the American version. It can sometimes occur in the British group too when there may be confusion over meaning, but that isn't the case here